# Error with relational mapping on new server

Tags: orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I just moved a custom built CMS over to a live server (it was on the development server) because it is easier to set up RSS.  The problem is that none of my relational mappings work anymore, despite me changing the `application.cfclocation` to reflect the new path.  It uses an absolute path, as well.  The setup is like so:

`F:\...\cmsRoot\com\dac`   (this is the original path)
`F:\...\cmsRoot\admin\com\dac`  (this is the path on the new server.  The only difference is the extra layer for the admin folder; the drive letters are the same)

The `Application.cfc` and most pages are located in the `cmsRoot` and `cmsRoot\admin` folders, respectively.  The `dac` folders contain my relational CFC files.

Originally, when loading each cfc for the first time Coldfusion would throw an error saying
`"Error Occurred While Processing Request

Cannot load the target CFC abc for the relation property abc in CFC xyz`
for each relational mapping (I commented them out to make sure every single one had the same problem).

After I added the line `<cfscript>ORMReload();</cfscript>` to the beginning of each CFC file, I could get past this error and access the login page just fine.  However, now I get an error any time I try to create an entity:

`Mapping for component abc not found.`

The first instance that calls it (and throws the error) looks like this:
`objectABC = EntityToQuery(EntityLoad("abc", {ActiveInd=1}));`

I've already searched for any related problems on stackoverflow already, and it helped me fix the original error by adding ORMReload() calls.  However, that doesn't solve the current problem.  I've changed the mapping for the CFC's (in the `Application.cfc`) to use a relative path, and that did not help either (since I figured it was likely a mapping issue).  I also checked folder permissions to make sure they matched, since one user said that fixed their problem.  Both folders have the same permissions, as well.

Here's any useful `Application.cfc` info, if that helps:

```
this.ormsettings = { cfclocation = ["F:\...\cmsRoot\admin\com\dac", "F:\...\cmsRoot\admin\com"]
                     , dialect="MicrosoftSQLServer"
                     , eventHandling = true
                   };
```

The only difference I can find between the `Application.cfc` files on the two servers is the filepaths.  Database is set up correctly, and the pages themselves have no problems (that I know of).

Another thing I've found is that commenting out any relational mappings causes everything to load correctly (minus any objectABC.getXYZ() calls since I removed those properties).

I have also restarted the Coldfusion application server, but there were no noticeable differences.

Is it possible that an `Application.cfc` farther up in the file structure is overriding any cfclocation settings I set up?  I didn't think this would be the case, but since nothing seems amiss with my `Application.cfc`, I am out of ideas.  And the application.cfc/.cfm lookup order (under "Settings" in the CFIDE administrator) is the same for both; set as default.

I have also tried removing the extra folder layer (so all mappings are the same), but the error is identical.

Update:  By adding a specific mapping for /cmsRoot (to F:...\cmsRoot), I get a new error that the components are not persistent.  However, all my cfc's start like this:

```
component persistent = "true" entityName = .....
```

Is there a reason why Coldfusion would think the entities aren't persistent even though I defined it otherwise?  And yes, I have used `ormReload()` to make sure it is updated properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to add a specific mapping to the `cmsRoot` folder by using `application.mappings['\cmsRoot'] = 'F:\...\cmsRoot';` in my `Application.cfc` file.

I had some old `ormReload()` calls at the top of all the `.cfc` files because that allowed some things to work; by deleting those calls it now loads properly.